# what is the default location where metrics are stored after installing collectd?

Tags: centos7, collectd

I installed Collectd in CentOS 7.2 I followed the link. 
http://www.tecmint.com/install-collectd-and-collectd-web-to-monitor-server-resources-in-linux/2/

After I started Collectd from what I read the one of the default metric is CPU. I was not able to find the location where this information is collected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collectd provides mechanisms to store those metrics in different ways. One being in RRD files.

If you choose that method, you'd want to enable the plugin `rrdtool` in `/etc/collectd.conf` and specifically set the Directory to store those files as well:

```
LoadPlugin rrdtool

<Plugin rrdtool>
     DataDir "/var/lib/collectd/rrd"
</Plugin>
```